# Always-on visual indicator to denote elevated processes in Windows

Tags: windows, processes

First off, I realize there are a number of ways to determine whether or not a process is elevated, but I'd like to be able to tell at a glance. Simple question: Is there a program that will add a visual indicator to the windows of elevated processes? Examples might include added caption text or a colored border around the window.

Comment: Would you mind listing some of the ways to determine if a process runs elevated? If we don't get answers here, the question is at least helpful then

Comment: "Processes" might not be the 100% correct term here, since there may be processes that don't have a window. Adding a border would only apply to windows.